# Keep image centered

Tags: html, css

I have this simple html:

```
<img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/XWGszmviDpA/maxresdefault.jpg" class="bg">
```

So far i centered the image correctly as long as the window is not smaller than the image. Now i have problems to keep the face in the middle when the window is smaller! How can i fix this?
For me its important that the image height stays 100% of the window.

My css:

```
img.bg {  
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
```

}

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/67jDp/1/

Comment: Can the image be displayed as a background?

Comment: Try `max-width:100%`, but keep in mind that it may break aspect ratio. @MarcAudet's suggestion of a background image is more reliable, if it's doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this with little javascript

css :

```
img.bg {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left:50%;
}
```

JS :

```
var i = $('img');
var w = i.width();

i.css({marginLeft: -w/2});

$( window ).resize(function() {
    i.css({marginLeft: -w/2});
});
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/67jDp/4/

Answer (score 2):

Try using it as a `background-image`.
CSS:

```
.bg {
    background-image:url('http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/XWGszmviDpA/maxresdefault.jpg');
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;   
    width:70%; //Custom dimension
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover; 
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/67jDp/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the image as the background of a `div` instead of an `img` tag

http://jsfiddle.net/CeVwN/1/

```
.bg {
    background-image:url('http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/XWGszmviDpA/maxresdefault.jpg');
    background-position:center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `width to 100%` to get always the container's width. Then, set `height to auto` to allow the ratio:

```
img.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;   
}
```

Remember to set a `max-width` to stop expanding when necessary.